# How to use one function to Insert and update using the same button name

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, insert-update

I have a button which is called Save. when you double click on the grid from(Tab1). data is being loaded to the textboxes so that you can edit on Tab2. so all my fields are on Tab2 which allows you to Save into the Database. when you load the page and click Tab2. you will be fill all the textbox and click save button. Now i want to edit using the same Tab2 abd button called Save,using the same funtion

I want to  use the Save function to perform Insert and update. how can i do that. am sure its an if statement to check for the Id but i dont know how to do it.

Working Insert Code:

```
   public async Task<bool> AddFleet(FleetModel fleet)
    {
        bool IsDone = false;
        try
        {
            using (SidDbContext db = new SidDbContext())
            {
                FleetVehicle fv = new FleetVehicle()
                {
                    BranchId = fleet.BranchId,
                    Description = fleet.Description,
                    Registration = fleet.Registration

                };
                db.FleetVehicle.Add(fv);
                db.SaveChanges();

                Fleet _fleet = new Fleet
                {
                    FitmentTeamId = Convert.ToInt32(fleet.FitmentTeamId),
                    Capacity = fleet.Capacity,
                    BranchId = fleet.BranchId,
                    Active = true                     
                };
               var results = db.Fleet.Add(_fleet);
                db.SaveChanges();

                db.FleetVehicleLink.Add(new FleetVehicleLink { FleetId = _fleet.Id ,FleetVehicleId = fv .Id});
                db.SaveChanges();
                //add team

                foreach (var u in fleet.TeamMember1)
                {
                    db.FitmentUsersLink.Add(new FitmentUsersLink { FitmentTeamId = _fleet.Id, UsersId = u });                       
                }

                db.SaveChanges();

                IsDone = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return IsDone = true;
    }
```

//

```
  function AddFleets() {

var multiSelect = $("#ddlTeamMember").data("kendoMultiSelect");   
var Fleet = {
    Id: 0,
    BranchId: $('#ddlOutlet').val(),
    Registration: $('#txtNewVehicle').val(),
    Description: $('#txtVehicleDescription').val(),
    FitmentTeamId: $('#ddlTeamName').val(),
    TeamMember1: multiSelect.value(),
    Capacity: $("#ddlCapacity").val(),
    Active: true
};

$.ajax({
    url: BaseUrl + "Fleet/AddFleet",
    global: false,
    type: 'Post',
    data: Fleet
});
success: function(data)
{
    alert('added successfully');
};
error: function(data)
{
    alert('error occurred');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a method "InsertOrSave(bool isInsert)" the handles the insert and add functionality, 
and two handlers for button clicks (one for save and another for insert), 
This handlers will call into the business logic function with the proper flag.

that way, you separate between business logic and GUI logic. and in the future, you could change the handlers methods ((add validations, log, raise events etc..) without affecting the business logic

**EDIT**

In your AddFleet method:

1) create your FleetVehicle from the fleetModel (as you currently do),

2) check if the FleetVehicle exists in the db, something like:

```
       FleetVehicle fv = new FleetVehicle()
                {
                    BranchId = fleet.BranchId,
                    Description = fleet.Description,
                    Registration = fleet.Registration

                };
     if (db.FleetVehicle.Contains(fv)
{
//update the item
}
else
{
//add the vehicle
}
db.SaveChanges()
```

**Note**

You should save the changes only once, after you finished making the changes.
when your in the context of your using statement, all changes that you make are aggregated and stored locally. calling "SaveChanges()" generated a call to the DB and it's redundant to do it multiple times.

Comment: Can you please give me steps to follow on the code provided?

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable flag.

Check if the data is already present in the database. If yes set flag=true if not then set flat=false

Now you can add condition on flag like

```
if(flag=true) then
update query
else
insert query
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Please have a look on my updated code and edit from the code pprovide

Answer (score 0):

You can pass type parameter into the function to check at JavaScript side that the call is for insert or update.
Ex. of button for passing type parameter

```
<input type="button" value="save" onclick="AddFleets(type)"/>
```

And JavaScript code will be like below

```
function AddFleets(type){

    if(type == "insert")
    {
       //Insert code
    }
    else
    {
       //update code
    }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look on my updated code and edit from the code pprovide

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple task and you can do it like this:

1. Add a new property to your ViewModel of type bool, and initialized to false
   (ex: `public bool IsEdit {get;set;} = false`)
2. on your view add a hidden field for this new property; 
   (ex: `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.IsEdit)`;
3. On grid double click event, when you load data in edit form you must change the value of IsEdit to true
4. In your controller you need to check if the IsEdit=true then you make update, else you insert new Record.

this also can be done with the ID field, you can have a hidden field, and in controller you check if ID>0 then is update, or ID=0, then is New!